# Import .bmp, .png, or .jpg into the javascript for office add-in browser

Tags: javascript, html, ms-office, office-js

Does anyone know if it is possible to import a .bmp, .jpg, or .png into the browser of a javascript office add-in?  I'd like to be able to import it from the user's file system and insert it into an svg component I have there.  Any ideas?

I'm using Excel and I have the javascript Taskpane add-in with an SVG component with some user functionality.  Is there a way to get a photo from the user's file system in there?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is no, for security reasons websites are not allowed to import/inspects anything from users file system. Until the user him self upload the file to the add-in(web application).

Why do you want to import from users file system, if there are some files you would like to in your add-in deploy them in your web application(add-in web application).

If you want to something from users, you can provide a file upload functionality in your app.

Comment: Well I want a company logo to be able to be imported into the svgs graphics.  What about the html5 filechooser?  Can that allow uploading?

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I should be able to upload into the html as a tag?

Comment: I think I found a nice demo here for anybody in the future: https://html5demos.com/file-api-simple/